# Return ChildClass.class pointer in method which returns Class<T extends BaseClass>

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that is supposed to analyze a `String` and determine the correct `Class<T>`, where `T extends BaseClass`.

Suppose that `BaseClass` is extended by `Child1`, `Child2` and `Child3`.

In my method, I want to do something like this:

```
public <T extends BaseClass> Class<T> from(String number) {
    if (number.contains("Child1")) {
        return Child1.class;
    } else if (number.contains("Child2")) {
        return Child2.class;
    } else if (number.contains("Child3")) {
        return Child3.class;
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot recognize class from " + number);
}
```

The problem is that the above method doesn't compile on all `return` statements, because `Required type is Class<T>, provided is Class<Child1>` (same for `Child2` and `Child3` of course).

Hence, I am forced to (unchecked) cast:

```
return (Class<T>) Child1.class;
```

... which of course works fine, since `Child1.class` is compatible with `Class<T>`.

How can I do what I'm trying to do in a cleaner way (without having the warning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... which of course works fine, since `Child1.class` is compatible with `Class<T>`.

That's incorrect. Understandable, as you're making a common mistake.

### The fix

The fix is to have the return type be `Class<? extends T>` instead. But, scratch that...

### But this code is bad style

Generics serve to link things. Any type variable should therefore be declared once and used in at least 2 places, or it is one of:

- useless.
- actively misleading.
- a type-safety breaking hack.

I assume you intended none of that. You have declared T once, and are using it once, which therefore means it's incorrect. The correct version is:

```
public Class<? extends BaseClass> from(String number) { ... }
```

This does everything you want. Specifically, something like this:

```
BaseClass bc = from("Child3").getConstructor().newInstance();
```

will just compile, no need for casts (you will need to festoon this up with rather a lot of try/catch, but no need for a cast, at least), and the compiler will not emit type safety warnings either. Which, presumably, is what you're trying to accomplish.

### Explanation

In java, typing relationships are **covariant**. That means **any type can stand in for any of its supertypes**.

In other words:

```
Number n = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

is valid java.

But the thing that generics are for simply doesn't adhere to this rule. Here is a trivial example. Imagine generics was just as covariant as basic type usage in java would be. Then I could write this, it would compile, and that would be bad, because this code would then be breaking the typing system:

```
List<Integer> listOfInts = List.of(1, 2, 3);
List<Number> listOfNums = listOfInts;
listOfNums.add(Double.valueOf(5.5));
int value = listOfInts.get(3);
```

Go through the above code and you realize there's a fundamental issue here.

The fix is that generics are **invariant** - **a type is a valid standin only for itself; not for anything else**.

In other words, the one and only thing you can assign to a `List<Number>` is an expression of type `List<Number>` or perhaps `ArrayList<Number>` ( because the non-generics part is covariant, we're talking only about the stuff in the `<>`), **not** `List<Integer>`.

That's the fix - that's why the above code isn't actually a problem for the typing system in java - it simply won't compile.

Now, when there is no such thing as 'adding', this becomes dubious, and `Class` is just such a type: Yes it's got a type param but you can't 'break stuff' if generics was covariant. Unfortunately, the generics feature of java does not ship with a gigantic list of 'the generics on THIS type can be covariant, but here they cannot be'.

Instead, java lets you choose your variance, and the APIs change to reflect what that means:

```
List<? extends Number> list = someListOfIntegers; // co-variance
List<? super Number> list = someListOfObject; // contra-variance
List list = someListOfAnything; // legacy-variance a.k.a. raw
List<Number> list = someListOfNumber; // invariance
```

Of course, you don't get this stuff for free: That covariant list (`List<? extends Number>`), you **cannot** call `add` on this list, **at all**. Well, the literal `.add(null)`, because null is a standin for all types, that works, but nothing else will, add is always a compile time error. That's the cost. If you opt out of all add methods on a list, then and only then can you write a method that accepts as parameter a list of numbers, or integers, or doubles, etc.

With `Class` it gets dubious (as there's no 'writing'), but the co/contra/invariant system is baked into generics and doesn't care about the fact that Class doesn't have any add-style methods in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the explanations and tips. I agree with you, I'll review this part of code to make it more stable.